# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'response.profileObj' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-google-login

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const responseGoogle = (response) => {

  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));

  const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;

  const doc = {
    _id: googleId,
    _type: 'user',
    userName: name,
    image: imageUrl,
  };

  client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
    navigate('/', { replace: true });
  });
};
```

I get an error that "name is undefined" – but how? What's the problem with `name`?
I've been dealing with this for a long time and I still can't figure it out

Comment: There is no problem with `name`. The error is telling you, that `response.profileObj` is `undefined`, thus it cannot be destructured.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by installing and an additional package:

```
npm install gapi-script
```

I imported it in my code:

```
import { gapi } from "gapi-script"
```

I also imported useEffect from react:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
```

I then defined a function and included my clientId. A snippet of my code implementation looked like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { gapi } from "gapi-script";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";

import { client } from "../client";

function Login() {

  const clientId =
    "360735963044-**********1l8rgmacmsmr9p4la9b47.apps.googleusercontent.com";

  useEffect(() => {
    const initClient = () => {
      gapi.client.init({
        clientId: clientId,
        scope: "",
      });
    };
    gapi.load("client:auth2", initClient);
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));
    const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;
    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: "user",
      userName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    };
    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    });
  };
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Google response has 3 responses types. On success response : `GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline`, on failure response : `error`.

`profileObj` exist only on the `GoogleLoginResponse` type. So, if you have an other reponse type, `profileObj` will be undefined, and you can't destructure the name.

You have to manage it.

```
export interface GoogleLoginProps {
  readonly onSuccess?: (response: GoogleLoginResponse | GoogleLoginResponseOffline) => void,
  readonly onFailure?: (error: any) => void,
  //...
}
```

```
// Based on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference
export interface GoogleLoginResponse {
  getBasicProfile(): BasicProfile;
  getAuthResponse(includeAuthorizationData?: boolean): AuthResponse;
  reloadAuthResponse(): Promise<AuthResponse>;
  getGrantedScopes(): string;
  getHostedDomain(): string;
  getId(): string;
  isSignedIn(): boolean;
  hasGrantedScopes(scopes: string): boolean;
  disconnect(): void;
  grantOfflineAccess(options: GrantOfflineAccessOptions): Promise<GoogleLoginResponseOffline>;
  signIn(options: SignInOptions): Promise<any>;
  grant(options: SignInOptions): Promise<any>;
  // google-login.js sez: offer renamed response keys to names that match use
  googleId: string;
  tokenObj: AuthResponse;
  tokenId: string;
  accessToken: string;
  readonly code?: string;//does not exist but here to satisfy typescript compatibility
  profileObj: {
    googleId: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    givenName: string;
    familyName: string;
  }
}
```

```
export interface GoogleLoginResponseOffline {
  readonly code: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing off of o.c answer:

> Google response has 3 responses types: GoogleLoginResponse, GoogleLoginResponseOffline, or error. Only GoogleLoginResponse has the profileObj property.

Perhaps changing the below line:

```js
const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;
```

To the below would help avoid the crash:

```js
const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj ?? {};
```

Your still going to need to address the underlying issue in other ways. But null-coalescing would stop the crash.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait for name from response. I did this and it worked.

```
     const navigate = useNavigate();
  const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    if (!response.profileObj) return;
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.profileObj));
    const { name, googleId, imageUrl } = response.profileObj;

    const doc = {
      _id: googleId,
      _type: 'user',
      userName: name,
      image: imageUrl,
    };

    client.createIfNotExists(doc).then(() => {
      navigate('/', { replace: true });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is genrate due to not destrucher of name correctly. So, you need to firstly add this line `if (!response.profileObj) return;` in your code. Then your code will work successfully.
[image: This is correct answer]